# Array out of bounds error when running this code in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code below and it keeps giving me a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. I can't seem to spot where the error is coming from. I know there is something wrong with the for loop but it doesn't pop out at me. I am trying to shift the character 1 space to the right from the original array to the new array. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HW3_1N {
 static final int ROWS = 8;
 static final int COLS = 16;

 public char[][] shiftChars(char newAr[][]) {
  char[][] x = new char[ROWS][COLS];
  for (int i = 0; i < newAr.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < newAr[i].length; j++) {
    if (newAr[i][j] < (char) 32 || newAr[i][j] > (char) 126) {

     x[i][j] = (char) 32;
    } else if (j >= newAr[i].length) {
     int lastchar = newAr[i].length;
     x[i][lastchar] = newAr[i][0];
     break;

    } else if (newAr[i][j] > (char) 32 || newAr[i][j] < (char) 126 || j < newAr[i].length) {
     int added = j + 1;
     x[i][j] = newAr[i][added];

    }
   }
  }
  return x;
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  char[][] array = new char[ROWS][COLS];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
    array[i][j] = (char)(i * COLS + j);

  System.out.println("Original Array of characters:");
  System.out.println("_______________________________");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
    if (array[i][j] < (char) 32 || array[i][j] > (char) 126)
     System.out.print("" + '\u0240' + ' ');
    else
     System.out.print("" + array[i][j] + ' ');
   System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println("_______________________________");
  char[][] result = null;
  HW3_1N o = new HW3_1N();
  result = o.shiftChars(array);

  System.out.println("\n\nNew Array from shiftChars(): ");
  System.out.println("_______________________________");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
    if (result[i][j] < (char) 32 || result[i][j] > (char) 126)
     System.out.print("" + '\u0240' + ' ');
    else
     System.out.print("" + result[i][j] + ' ');
   System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println("_______________________________");
 }
```

}

Comment: `|| j < newAr[i].length` should be `|| (j+1) < newAr[i].length`

Comment: The exception happens at `x[i][j] = newAr[i][added];` after `int added = j + 1;` When j is 15 then added becomes 16 and this index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
int added = j + 1;
```

So, at the end of the loop you are indexing (j + 1)th element , thus out of bounds exception. The loop should run till

```
int j = 0; j < newAr[i].length-1; j++
```

But since this shifts your output, you can just set

```
      if (j < newAr[i].length-1){
          added = j+1;
      }
      else{
          added = 0;
      }
 x[i][added] = newAr[i][j];
```

[image: This is your original one]

[image: This is your updated one without any shifted columns and array intact]

The newly shaped array has the orientation intact and I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: This did not fix the problem because it is now moving everything a space back instead of forward.

Comment: Just make `added = j` and keep the loop intact. It will work for you.

Comment: I need the new array to shift everything over one space to the right and the last space should go to the first index.